# how to pull up the last entry of each product

Tags: php, mysql

I have an inventory table that gets updated with each transaction. Currently there are 4 products, but at some point there may be more. The following is the table I used to pull everything.

---

```
    <?php
$db = new mysqli('', '', '', 'inventory');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

echo "<table style='border: 2px;font-family: tahoma;'><caption><b>Entire Database Contents</b></caption><tr><td>ID</td><td>Time Stamp</td><td>Staff</td><td>Client</td><td>Needed</td><td>Product</td><td>Amount</td><td>Totals</td><td style='width: 200px;'>Comments</td></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['timeStamp'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['staff'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['client'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['dateNeeded'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['product'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['amt'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['tot'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['comments'] . '</td></tr>';
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

---

What I'd like to do is to pull ONLY the most recent entries of each product. I'm thinking maybe DISTINCT and LAST probably comes into play here but have no idea how to set it up. Any pointers?

Comment: So currently, I have 4 products. the table would only have 4 rows with the most recent activity for each product. Some of the entries are the same product 2 or more times in a row. Do I need to go back into the db 4 times to get each product or can it loop through things and pull up the last entry of each of the 4 products. At some point there will be more products added. That's why I'd like the loop.

Comment: Still struggling. With each of these examples, its listing everything in the database. I only want it to look for the last entry of each product according to the timestamp. I can get it to do this by doing 4 mysql's, but I would think it should be able to look for the most recent update (from the timestamp) of each product and list the product and total.

This is basically what I'd like it to look like. Product name and how many we have in inventory. Pit Crew SE 69 Pit Crew B 0 Cooltron - Cooling 3 Cooltron - Heat and Cool 7

Its entirely possible that I'm not getting something too.

Answer (score 1):

You should create date_added field and sort by it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY date_added DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select only the products with `MAX` timestamp:

```
SELECT i.* FROM inventory i
JOIN (SELECT product, MAX(timestamp) timestamp FROM inventory GROUP BY product) i2
ON i2.product = i.product
AND i2.timestamp = i.timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select distinct product, id, timeStamp, staff, client, dateNeeded,  amt, tot, comments from inventory order by timestamp desc;
```